# How to use NSDateFormatter with NSPopUpButton

Tags: cocoa, nsdateformatter, nspopupbuttoncell

I have an NSPopUpButton's content bound to an Array Controller of "Meeting" entities and it's content value bound to the same array controller, but to the "date" model key path. Everything works fine. But I'd like to format the way the date is displayed with an NSDateFormatter and I can't get it to work. Any hints? Is it even possible?

Comment: How have you hooked up the date formatter?

Comment: Hi Peter,

I just dragged and dropped it onto the Pop Up Button in IB. IB puts it "inside" the Pop Up Button Cell, on the same level as the Menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, some guys on Twitter suggested adding a formattedDate method to my model. I knew from the get go that I could do that but was hoping that there's some IB-only solution. I don't think there is, so to answer my own question: NSDateFormatter doesn't (seem to) work with NSPopUpButton.

My formattedDate method looks like this:

```
- (NSString *)formattedDate {
  return [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:self.date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
}
```